# problem with query two different tables with foreign key relations

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am having a problem with querying two tables with different foreign key relations... My first query works fine but when adding another table with a different set of relations I am having a problem... Can some one point me in the right direction.

First Query works:

```
select `title`,`txt`,`img`
from `content_m2m`
inner join `content`
on `content_m2m`.`content` = `content`.`cid`
inner join `links`
on `content_m2m`.`links` = `links`.`lid`
inner join `category`
on `content_m2m`.`category` = `category`.`catid`
where `content_m2m`.`keywords` like '%test%';
```

Second query that I am stuck when adding another table:

```
select `title`,`txt`,`img`
from `content_m2m`
inner join `content`
on `content_m2m`.`content` = `content`.`cid`
inner join `links`
on `content_m2m`.`links` = `links`.`lid`
inner join `category`
on `content_m2m`.`category` = `category`.`catid`
where `content_m2m`.`keywords` like '%test%' OR (
select `firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`mi`,`dName`,`phnumber`
from `staff`
inner join `departments`
on `staff`.`department` = `departments`.`did`
inner join `phones`
on `staff`.`phone` = `phones`.`pid`
where `staff`.`keywords` like '%test%');
```

Comment: Table definitions would help. Consider creating a SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the schema and some sample data.

Comment: I tried and it comes up with a #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)... Which I am trying to receive all the results that are in both query's.

Comment: `...'%test%' OR (select...` Question: Are you expecting all of those columns to become candidate keywords? They will not: They are six different columns.

Comment: Well the select statement on both queries (ex. 1st - title, txt, img and subquery firstname, lastname, email, mi, dname, phnumber i would like to display from searching through the keywords column on both statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to combine result sets from different tables, use the UNION operator with two queries. Since the sets have different and unrelated column names, you will need to select a placeholder (usually NULL) in each query for columns in the other query:

```
select `title`,`txt`,`img`,
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
from `content_m2m`
inner join `content`
on `content_m2m`.`content` = `content`.`cid`
inner join `links`
on `content_m2m`.`links` = `links`.`lid`
inner join `category`
on `content_m2m`.`category` = `category`.`catid`
where `content_m2m`.`keywords` like '%test%'
UNION
select NULL, NULL, NULL,
`firstname`,  `lastname`, `email`, `mi`, `dName`, `phnumber`
from `staff`
inner join `departments`
on `staff`.`department` = `departments`.`did`
inner join `phones`
on `staff`.`phone` = `phones`.`pid`
where `staff`.`keywords` like '%test%';
```

Comment: @smor - if this solved your problem, would you mind marking the answer as correct?